# Mimic exposure value on a Drawable

Tags: android, image-processing, android-drawable

I'm trying to animate the exposure value of a `Drawable` as part of a transition. In this same transition I'm adjusting the saturation via a `ColorFilter`. I'm wondering if there are any ways to mimic adjusting this value that would be compatible with a `ColorMatrix` or other quick transformation. The values would need to be calculated in the middle of a `draw()` method, so there's not enough time to calculate gamma correction (unless you know of a quick way that can operate on a `Drawable` and not a `Bitmap`). At the same time, the frame will be shown for a small enough time that getting it perfect isn't important as long as it's smooth.

The full effect I'm going for is described at http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/imagery-treatment.html#imagery-treatment-image-load